# Attribute srcset incorrectly working in Safari

Tags: ios, safari, srcset

I have problem with attribute srcset in Safari browser! So if I want make window smaller and then load the page (after clearing the cache / or use incognito mode). Then by making the window bigger, but browser not switching to higher resolution picture. Same things on iPhone 6 and iPad on orientation change. Here is my code:

```
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/414x500/CD853F/ffffff?text=Mobile+image+414px"
             srcset="http://via.placeholder.com/414x500/CD853F/ffffff?text=Mobile+image+414px 414w,
                    http://via.placeholder.com/980x500/CD853F/ffffff?text=Tablet+image+980px 980w,
                    http://via.placeholder.com/1280x500/CD853F/ffffff?text=Landscape+image+1280px 1280w,
                    http://via.placeholder.com/1920x500/CD853F/ffffff?text=Desktop+image+1920px 1920w"
             sizes="100vw"
             alt="image description">
```

Comment: Try putting srset attribute before src